# Can i have more than one Post method in asp.net mvc controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have two views, one is CustomerDetail.cshtml and another is PAymentDetail.cshtml and i have one controller QuoteController.cs.

Both the Views has  Submit buttons and HTTPPOST method for both the views are in QuoteController.cs.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CustomerDetail(FormCollection form)
{
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PAymentDetail(FormCollection form)
{
}
```

Now, when i click on Submit button of Payment details, it is calling/routing to HttpPost method of CustomerDetail rather than PAymentDetail.

Could anyone help me on this?? What i'm doing wrong? Both The form method is POST.

Comment: You may want to check your routing configuration, especially if you have modified it from the default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the PaymentDetail, you use this in the view:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("PAymentDetail","Quote",FormMethod.Post)) 
{
  //Form element here 
}
```

The result html will be

```
<form action="/Quote/PAymentDetail" method="post"></form>
```

The same for customer Detail

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("CustomerDetail","Quote",FormMethod.Post)) 
{
  //Form element here
}
```

Hope that help. Having two post methods in the same controller is not a problems, as long as these methods have different names.

For a better way other than FormCollection, I recommend this.
First, you create a model.

```
public class LoginModel
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

}
```

Then, in the view:

```
@model LoginModel
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {

<fieldset>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName)
        //Insted of razor tag, you can create your own input, it must have the same name as the model property like below.
        <input type="text" name="Username" id="Username"/>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)    
    </div>
</fieldset>
  }
```

These user input will be mapped into the controller.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model)
{
   String username = model.Username;
   //Other thing
}
```

Good luck with that.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely! Just ensure you are posting to the right action method, check your rendered HTML's `form` tags.

Also, the `FormCollection` isn't a good design for MVC.

Comment: You could add some info on some good design :) Like taking in a `class` or such instead.

Comment: I have some <input> tags, that are not created using razor view, these values need to be captured in the controller method. Do u know any better  way of doing this (other than FormCollection). And also, can we have two post method in same controller?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have only one url, here is another approach: http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=724

The idea is to use a form element (the button or a hidden element) to decide, which form has been submitted. Then you write a custom action selector (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionmethodselectorattribute.aspx) which decides which action will be invoked.